# DNS Problem

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, domain-name-system

I just install a Windows 2003 on my server, and dont enable it's DNS server , I have a problem on this system, and can't open Microsoft web sites ( All Microsoft.com , and its subdomains) and dont have any problem from other pc on Lan or for other web sites? ( I can't ping microsoft,com) how can I fix this problem?
Also I can't open any AntiVirus web sites

Thanks

Comment: What are the interface settings pointing to for DNS?  Are you sure you have a good working connection?  Can you ping other known sites by IP?

Comment: I can view other sites and can ping yahoo , msn and many others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ISC maintains a collection of removal tools [here](http://www.dshield.org/diary.html?storyid=5860), though I would most definitely be reformatting a machine that was infected with Conficker.

Some other things to consider:

- Conficker spreads quite rapidly across unpatched networks, so try one of the scanners available on that page on your network to be sure your machine hasn't infected others.
- You should also take a look at any removable media (USB keys) that have been used in that machine recently, not only to possibly trace the source of the infection but also to be sure it's not spreading that way.

Ehtyar.

Comment: "I would most definitely be reformatting a machine that was infected with Conficker", - do you also, you know, sprinkle your machines with holy water after you reformat them, because of them being infected with Conficker? :P Beacause, you see, reformatting seems like a bit of a waste of time to me.. Just remove the damn thing from the system and get on with it.

Comment: Thanks , as I find in this link by this command net stop dnscache , my problem fixed now

Comment: You may be snide if you wish shylent, it is simply my personal opinion that machines are not to be trusted once they have been breached in this manner. If your machine is infected, it is clear your antivirus and patching process have failed at some stage, particularly when the infection occurs this late in the game (Conficker has been around for over 6 months now). In an organization it is naturally infeasible to reformat every machine that's infected, but my own *personal* machine, yes it would be reformatted.

I'm glad to hear the cause was not Conficker, congratulations Ashian :)

Ehtyar.

Comment: I am sorry, Ehtyar Holmes, if my comment sounded offensive to you, I did not mean it this way, honestly. Anyway, if it was MY personal machine, I would, probably do the same, because if I've messed up like that, I deserve going through the reformatting process.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like a Conficker infection. I can't post more than one link at a time, so try running the test [here](http://www.confickerworkinggroup.org/infection_test/cfeyechart.html) and let us know the results.

Ehtyar.

Comment: result : Possibly Infected by Conficker A/B variant

Answer (score 0):

1. `ipconfig/all` - Does the server have a valid IP address?
2. Is the default gateway on the server correct?
3. Can you ping the gateway?
4. Have you assigned the DNS server for the server to use, and can you ping them?
5. Can you ping an IP address in your network segment
6. Can you ping an IP address outside of your network segment (i.e., through your gateway)
7. Use netstat to resolve some DNS names, but by this step, I would suspect some of the above steps have already failed.

Comment: 1- no server doesnt have.
2- i dont set gateway for server, it's ip is 192.168.1.1
3-
4- I use 208.67.222.222 and can ping
5 I can ping my local IP
6- I can ping many sites , just microsft.com and some antivirus web sites dont work

Comment: Well then you need to fix `1' first, without an IP address, DNS resolution is the least of your problems.